# SCRAPY FORM REQUEST doesn't return any data

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, http-post

I was making a form request to a website. The request is made successfully but it's not returning any data.

### LOGS:

```
2020-09-05 22:37:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp> (referer: https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/)
2020-09-05 22:37:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp> (referer: https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/)
2020-09-05 22:37:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp> (referer: https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/)
2020-09-05 22:37:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-09-05 22:37:59 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

### MY CODE:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

codes = open('codes.txt').read().split('\n')

class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main'
    form_url = 'https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp'
    start_urls = ['https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/CompanySnapshot.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):

        for code in codes:
        
            data = {
                'searchtype': 'ANY',
                'query_type': 'queryCarrierSnapshot',
                'query_param': 'USDOT',
                'query_string': code,
            }

            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=self.form_url, formdata=data, callback=self.parse_form)

    def parse_form(self, response):
        cargo = response.xpath('(//table[@summary="Cargo Carried"]/tbody/tr)[2]')
        for each in cargo:
            each_x = each.xpath('.//td[contains(text(), "X")]/following-sibling::td/font/text()').get()

            yield {
                "X Values": each_x if each_x else "N/A",
            }
```

The following are a few samples code that I am using for the POST REQUEST.

2146709

273286

120670

2036998

690147

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you need is to remove `tbody` from your XPath here:

```
    cargo = response.xpath('(//table[@summary="Cargo Carried"]/tbody/tr)[2]')
```

use like this:

```
    cargo = response.xpath('//table[@summary="Cargo Carried"]/tr[2]') 
    # I also removed the () inside the path because you don't need it, but that didn't cause the problem.
```

The reason for this is that Scrapy will parse the original code from the page, while your browser may render `tbody` in case it isn't in the source. Further info [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom).